# How to write a SQL query that "iterates" over values from another query

Tags: sql

I have a query like this (I am simplifying to try to be clear):

```
SELECT avg(p.age)
FROM Person p
WHERE p.name = "John"
GROUP BY name
```

Note there might be 50 people named John in Person, so I am getting the average of all their ages.

But what I really want to do is to have the query return the avg(p.age) for each name returned from another query, say {John, James, Sam, Mary}. Of course I have a query that can return all the names, such as (again, simplifying)

```
SELECT name
FROM Names
```

[Since in my real like database, Names are stored in a different table than Person]

That is, I want output from the one query to be something like the following and not have to run multiple queries with the name hard-coded in to each one:

```
John 37.5
Mary 27.9
James 42.0
Sam 17.6
```

Thank you for your thoughts!

I tried subqueries or recursive queries, but could not quite get what I needed.

Comment: `SELECT p.name, AVG(p.age) FROM Person p GROUP BY p.name` if you want everybody, or you could include `WHERE p.name IN ('John', 'Mary', 'James', 'Sam')` if you only want specific people. A [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be necessary if you want a more specific answer.

Comment: Never store age in your tables. People become older every year, and your data will soon be out-of-date. Store date of birth instead.

Answer (score 3):

From what you are describing, the following code should provide the desired output:

```
SELECT p.name, AVG(p.age)
FROM Person p
WHERE p.name IN (SELECT name
                 FROM Names)
GROUP BY p.name
```

The `WHERE` clause will select only the names retrived by the nested subquery. Then the `GROUP BY` clause will compute the average age of just the selected names.